# Filter/Exclude a directory when using QDirIterator in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, iterator

I'm wondering if it is possible to exclude/filter a directory when using QDirIterator. I would like it to skip over it/ignore it completely.

```
        QString SkipThisDir = "C:\stuff";

        QDirIterator CPath(PathToCopyFrom,  QDir::AllEntries | QDir::NoSymLinks, QDirIterator::Subdirectories );


            while(CPath.hasNext())
            {
                CPath.next();
                //DoSometing
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything in the API for QDirIterator that does specifically what you want. However, something as simple as the following would work.

```
while (CPath.hasNext())
{
    if (CPath.next() == SkipThisDir)
        continue;
    //DoSomething
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to add one more backslash to your `SkipThisDir` in order to escape it.

```
Second you could do a check at the beginning of the while loop and if the current folder is the one you want to skip you could continue to the next directory.

QString SkipThisDir = "C:\\stuff";

QDirIterator CPath(PathToCopyFrom,  QDir::AllEntries | QDir::NoSymLinks, 
                   QDirIterator::Subdirectories );


while(CPath.hasNext())
{
    QString currentDir = CPath.next();
    if (currentDir == SkipThisDir)
         continue; 
    //DoSometing
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work at least with Qt 5.4. When combining QDirInterator::IteratorFlag with QDir::Filters I get a compiler error `call of overloaded 'QDirIterator(QString&, int)' is ambiguous`.